# Integrate and determine if cauchy integral theorem applies

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

$$\int_c \frac{dz}{z-3i}$$

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z-3i}$$ where C the circle |z|=π counterclockwise.

So since f(z) is not analytic when z = 3i, we have to integrate another way since we cannot apply cauchy theorem of integrals.

$$\int_c \frac{1}{z - 3i}dz = \int_c (z - 3i)^{-1}$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: This is effectively the same question, modulo the constants of $az+b$ as you asked earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Using [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Evaluation_with_residue_theorem), as $z=3i$ is internal to the circle $|z|=\pi$
$$\oint_{|z|=\pi}\frac{dz}{z-3i}=2\pi i\text{Res}\left[\frac{1}{z-3 i},\{z,3 i\}\right]=2\pi i$$
because
$$\text{Res}\left[\frac{1}{z-3 i},\{z,3 i\}\right]=\underset{z\to 3 i}{\text{lim}}\frac{z-3 i}{z-3 i}=1$$